# Prevent TextIOWrapper from closing on GC in a Py2/Py3 compatible way

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, garbage-collection

What I need to accomplish:

Given a binary file, decode it in a couple different ways providing a **`TextIOBase`** API. Ideally these subsequent files can get passed on without my needing to keep track of their lifespan explicitly.

Unfortunately, wrapping a `BufferedReader` will 
result in that reader being closed when the `TextIOWrapper` goes out of scope.

Here is a simple demo of this:

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: def mangle(x):
   ...:     io.TextIOWrapper(x) # Will get GCed causing __del__ to call close
   ...:     

In [3]: f = io.open('example', mode='rb')

In [4]: f.closed
Out[4]: False

In [5]: mangle(f)

In [6]: f.closed
Out[6]: True
```

I can fix this in Python 3 by overriding `__del__` (this is a reasonable solution for my use case as I have complete control over the decoding process, I just need to expose a very uniform API at the end):

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: class MyTextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
   ...:     def __del__(self):
   ...:         print("I've been GC'ed")
   ...:         

In [3]: def mangle2(x):
   ...:     MyTextIOWrapper(x)
   ...:     

In [4]: f2 = io.open('example', mode='rb')

In [5]: f2.closed
Out[5]: False

In [6]: mangle2(f2)
I've been GC'ed

In [7]: f2.closed
Out[7]: False
```

However this does not work in Python 2:

```
In [7]: class MyTextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
   ...:     def __del__(self):
   ...:         print("I've been GC'ed")
   ...:         

In [8]: def mangle2(x):
   ...:     MyTextIOWrapper(x)
   ...:     

In [9]: f2 = io.open('example', mode='rb')

In [10]: f2.closed
Out[10]: False

In [11]: mangle2(f2)
I've been GC'ed

In [12]: f2.closed
Out[12]: True
```

I've spent a bit of time staring at the Python source code and it looks remarkably similar between 2.7 and 3.4 so I don't understand why the `__del__` inherited from `IOBase` is not overridable in Python 2 (or even visible in `dir`), but still seems to get executed. Python 3 works exactly as expected.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just **detach** your `TextIOWrapper()` object before letting it be garbage collected:

```
def mangle(x):
    wrapper = io.TextIOWrapper(x)
    wrapper.detach()
```

The `TextIOWrapper()` object only closes streams it is attached to. If you can't alter the code where the object goes out of scope, then simply keep a reference to the `TextIOWrapper()` object *locally* and detach at that point.

If you *must* subclass `TextIOWrapper()`, then just call `detach()` in the `__del__` hook:

```
class DetachingTextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __del__(self):
        self.detach()
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

[Just call `detach` first, thanks martijn-pieters!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54421867/579416)

---

It turns out there is basically nothing that can be done about the deconstructor calling `close` in Python 2.7. This is hardcoded into the C code. Instead we can modify `close` such that it won't close the buffer when `__del__` is happening (`__del__` will be executed before `_PyIOBase_finalize` in the C code giving us a chance to change the behaviour of `close`). This lets `close` work as expected without letting the GC close the buffer.

```
class SaneTextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._should_close_buffer = True
        super(SaneTextIOWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        # Accept the inevitability of the buffer being closed by the destructor
        # because of this line in Python 2.7:
        # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_io/iobase.c#L221
        self._should_close_buffer = False
        self.close()  # Actually close for Python 3 because it is an override.
                      # We can't call super because Python 2 doesn't actually
                      # have a `__del__` method for IOBase (hence this
                      # workaround). Close is idempotent so it won't matter
                      # that Python 2 will end up calling this twice

    def close(self):
        # We can't stop Python 2.7 from calling close in the deconstructor
        # so instead we can prevent the buffer from being closed with a flag.

        # Based on:
        # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/_pyio.py#L1586
        # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/_pyio.py#L1615
        if self.buffer is not None and not self.closed:
            try:
                self.flush()
            finally:
                if self._should_close_buffer:
                    self.buffer.close()
```

My previous solution here used `_pyio.TextIOWrapper` which is slower than the above because it is written in Python, not C.

It involved simply overriding `__del__` with a noop which will also work in Py2/3.

Comment: This is really overcomplicating matters. The only reason `TextIOWrapper()` closes the wrapped buffer is because it *attached to it*. You only need to `.detach()` the object to prevent it from closing the underlying object.

Comment: Gosh, that is so obvious, I'm pretty well removed from this problem nowadays, but thanks for providing the right solution after all these years :D

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to return the variable from the function and store it in script scope, so that it does not get garbage collected until the script ends or the reference to it changes. But there may be other elegant solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I found a much better solution (comparatively), but I will leave this answer in the event it is useful for anyone to learn from. (It is a pretty easy way to show off `gc.garbage`)

Please do not actually use what follows.

OLD:

I found a potential solution, though it is horrible:

What we can do is set up a cyclic reference in the destructor, which will hold off the GC event. We can then look at the `garbage` of `gc` to find these unreferenceable objects, break the cycle, and drop that reference.

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: class MyTextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
   ...:     def __del__(self):
   ...:         if not hasattr(self, '_cycle'):
   ...:             print "holding off GC"
   ...:             self._cycle = self
   ...:         else:
   ...:             print "getting GCed!"
   ...:

In [3]: def mangle(x):
   ...:     MyTextIOWrapper(x)
   ...:     

In [4]: f = io.open('example', mode='rb')

In [5]: mangle(f)
holding off GC

In [6]: f.closed
Out[6]: False

In [7]: import gc

In [8]: gc.garbage
Out[8]: []

In [9]: gc.collect()
Out[9]: 34

In [10]: gc.garbage
Out[10]: [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='example' encoding='UTF-8'>]

In [11]: gc.garbage[0]._cycle=False

In [12]: del gc.garbage[0]
getting GCed!

In [13]: f.closed
Out[13]: True
```

Truthfully this is a pretty horrific workaround, but it could be transparent to the API I am delivering. Still I would prefer a way to override the `__del__` of `IOBase`.