# Django ValueError: I/O operation on closed file, after using clean_<fieldname>() on FileField

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create a page with a formset to allow the user to upload CSV files, the contents of which I want to validate before saving.

I have a formset where each form has some CharFields pre-populated and then a FileField.

I want to validate the contents of the CSV before I save it to a location on the disk, as they must be a very specific format. My current code performs this validation in a custom `clean_<fieldname>()` function for the FileField in the form.

The validation all appears to work, however, when I attempt to write the file to the intended location on the disk I get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

I am using Python 3.4.3 with Django 1.11 and my code is below.
I've only included the function which is giving the error in csv_funcs.py, specifically on the call to `csv_f.chunks` which tries to do `self.file.seek(0)`.
The other functions in that file which perform validation don't explicitly call `close()` on the file object anywhere, although they do use `csv.DictReader` on it after which I always `seek(0)` to return to the start of the file.

forms.py

```
class CsvUploadForm(forms.Form):
    nom = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    machine = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['id'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
        self.fields['library'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
        self.fields['filepath'] = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': ".csv"}), required=False)
        self.metadata = defaultdict()

    def clean_filepath(self):
        csv_binary = self.cleaned_data.get('filepath')
        ## If they supplied a filepath, do some validation
        if csv_binary is not None:
            csv_file = TextIOWrapper(csv_binary, encoding='ASCII')
            version = csv_funcs._get_csv_version(csv_file)
            if version == bc_version.unknown:
                 raise forms.ValidationError("The CSV version could not be determined!")
            expected_name = csv_funcs._get_expected_name(self.cleaned_data['nom'], self.cleaned_data['id'], self.cleaned_data['library'], version)
            if csv_file.name != expected_name:
                self.add_error('filepath', forms.ValidationError("Filename did not match the expected name for this format! Expected {} but got {}".format(expected_name, csv_file.name)))
            self.metadata['version'] = version
            ## DO SOME VALIDATION
            content_info = csv_funcs._validate_contents(csv_file, version)
            self.metadata['num_bc'] = content_info[0]
            self.metadata['type'] = content_info[1]
            csv_binary.seek(0)

        return csv_binary
```

views.py

```
def process_uploads(request):
    UploadFormset = formset_factory(CsvUploadForm, extra=0)
    if request.method == "POST":
        uploads = UploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if uploads.is_valid():
            result_list = []
            for u in uploads:
                uclean = u.cleaned_data
                if uclean.get('filepath'):
                    csv_funcs._write_csv(uclean['filepath']), u.metadata['version'], uclean['nom'], uclean['machine'])
                    result = 'SAVED: {}_{}_{}_{}_{}_{}_{}_{}'.format(uclean['nom'], uclean['id'], uclean['machine'], uclean['library'], uclean['filepath'].name, u.metadata['version'], u.metadata['num_bc'], u.metadata['type'])
                else:
                    result = 'No file provided for {}_{}_{}_{}'.format(uclean['nom'], uclean['id'], uclean['machine'], uclean['library'])
                result_list.append(result)
            return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': result_list})
        else:
            return render(request, 'ids.html', {'formset': uploads, 'nom': 'FAIL', 'machine': 'FAIL'})
```

csv_funcs.py

```
def _write_csv(csv_f, version, nom, machine):
    output_path = os.path.expanduser(csv_dirs[version].substitute(nom=nom, machine=machine))
    os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)
    with open(os.path.join(output_path, csv_f.name), "wb") as f_out:
        for chunk in csv_f.chunks():
            f_out.write(chunk)
```

Trace

```
Traceback:

File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/barcode_uploader/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/barcode_uploader/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/barcode_uploader/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/admin/project_dev/barcode_uploader/upload_app/views.py" in process_uploads
  47.                   csv_funcs._write_csv(uclean['filepath']), u.metadata['version'], uclean['nom'], uclean['machine'])

File "/home/admin/project_dev/barcode_uploader/upload_app/csv_funcs.py" in _write_csv
  28.       for chunk in csv_f.chunks():

File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/barcode_uploader/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py" in chunks
  96.         self.file.seek(0)

Exception Type: ValueError at /upload_app/uploaded/
Exception Value: I/O operation on closed file.
```

**Potential Solution**

I think I have isolated the call to TextIOWrapper as the culprit. I have implemented the Python3 work-around from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993816/prevent-textiowrapper-from-closing-on-gc-in-a-py2-py3-compatible-way) and it now successfully saves, although I have no idea if avoiding the GC in this way is problematic.

Comment: full stacktrace please.

Comment: Added the traceback from the debug output, hope that is right